# Cannot render image in Github README in PNG format

Tags: github, markdown

[image: Some are PNG, some are png]

Why when push to Github, some image extension are in capital letters, some are not.
I use `<img src="images/i12.png" width="400"/>` to show image in Markdown.

Comment: ...that's just how the files are named. Nothing to do with Git, or GitHub, or Markdown. Don't you see the same thing in your local copy?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you add and commit the files in your git/github repository.
git/github itself doesn't change the file extension. Your files have those extension at the time you commit them.

You are referring to the images with a lower case extension, this is the reason your images are not shown. Change all the file extensions to lower case and recommit them.